# Extract data from $resource.get(...).$promise

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I use $resource to get data from Facebook's Graph api:

```
resource = $resource(
    "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/:api/:id/:node/"
)
```

So for instance, I made a successful request to 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/user.id/albums/' by:

```
resource.get({id:user_id, node: "albums", access_token: ....}).then(function(response)
{
    console.log(response)
})
```

and the response shows (in Chrome dev tool console):

```
Resource
- $promise: Promise
- $resolved: true
- data: Array[9] 
    - 0: Object
    - 1: Object2:
    - length: 9
    - __proto__: Array[0]
- paging: Object
- __proto__: Resource
```

So I naively try to add under `console.log response` another `console.log response.data`,

but it shows 'undefined'.

So I wonder how to extract the `data` object?

========================== *EDIT* ========================

It seems the reason being

```
resource.get({id:user_id, node: "albums", access_token: ....}).then(function(response)
{
    console.log(response)
})
```

is **chained** after another resource request as follows:

```
    FB.get_user().then(function(response) {
  var user_id;
  return user_id = response.id;
}).then(function(response) {
  return self.albums = FB.resource.get({
    id: user_id,
    node: "albums",
    access_token: Auth.get_user().social_account_access_token
  });
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log("response", response); # Log #1
  return console.log("response.data", response.data); # Log #2
});
```

In this case **Log #1** will log out the `resource` object with `data` being an array, while **Log #2** gives `undefined`.

If I do not chain the `then` function, but put the last one inside the previous `.then`, I have the expected results:

```
FB.get_user().then(function(response) {
  var user_id;
  return user_id = response.id;
}).then(function(response) {
  return self.albums = FB.resource.get({
    id: user_id,
    node: "albums",
    access_token: Auth.get_user().social_account_access_token
  }).$promise.then(function(response) {
    console.log("A: response", response);  # Log #1
    return console.log("response.data", response.data); # Log #2
  });
});
```

gives **Log #1** the same result, while **Log #2** is an array of 9 elements.

** So I wonder I is the problem of the original method?**

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening in your first attempt is that in your second `then()` you are returning the return value of `FB.resource.get()`, but this value is not a promise, so this `then()` resolves immediately, and processing moves on to the next `then()` before the data is done being retrieved. When you view the values in your Chrome debugger, you are stopping the execution long enough for the request to finish, and the data is populated when you observe it. (There is a [term for this phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug), by the way.)

According to the notes on [this pull request](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/angular.js/commit/37dc1d3f74f81e9b0a4a7d9010bab8b266b49da3) and [this note in the developer's guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#resource-then-has-been-removed), you should be using `instance.$promise` if you want to chain off of a resource request. So your second approach that uses `$promise` is more or less the correct way to go about it.

Your code can be cleaned up a bit. Unless you have a reason to want a separate step to extract the FB user id and pass it to the next step, you can remove the first `.then()`. There is some other tidying up that you can do as well:

```
FB.get_user()
.then(function (response) {
    var user_id = response.id;
    // the value assigned to self.albums here is a (mostly) empty object that will 
    // be populated with data when the request finishes
    self.albums = FB.resource.get({
        id: user_id,
        node: "albums",
        access_token: Auth.get_user().social_account_access_token
    });
    return self.albums.$promise;
})
.then(function (response) {
    // (avoid putting a [then] inside another [then] unless you need to)
    console.log("A: response", response);
    console.log("response.data", response.data);
    return response.data;
});
```